# Find directories that DON'T contain a file

Tags: bash, find

Yes, I'm sorting out my music. I've got everything arranged beautifully in the following mantra: `/Artist/Album/Track - Artist - Title.ext` and if one exists, the cover sits in `/Artist/Album/cover.(jpg|png)`.

I want to scan through all the second-level directories and find the ones that don't have a cover. By second level, I mean I don't care if `/Britney Spears/` doesn't have a cover.jpg, but I would care if `/Britney Spears/In The Zone/` didn't have one.

Don't worry about the cover-downloading (that's a fun project for me tomorrow) I only care about the glorious bash-fuiness about an inverse-ish `find` example.

Comment: for anyone who's interested in downloading the covers that are missing just install https://launchpad.net/coverlovin and replace the -print in @phoibos answer with "-exec ./coverlovin.py {} \;"

Comment: related: https://serverfault.com/questions/235025/list-directories-not-containing-a-file | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873834/list-directories-not-containing-certain-files | https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85448/list-all-directories-that-do-not-have-a-file-with-a-given-file-name-inside | https://superuser.com/questions/548476/list-subdirectories-one-level-down-that-do-not-contain-a-certain-file

Answer (score 120, accepted):

### Case 1: You know the exact file name to look for

Use `find` with `test -e your_file` to check if a file exists. For example, you look for directories which have no `cover.jpg` in them:

```
find base_dir -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d '!' -exec test -e "{}/cover.jpg" ';' -print
```

It's case sensitive though.

### Case 2: You want to be more flexible

You're not sure of the case, and the extension might be `jPg`, `png`...

```
find base_dir -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d '!' -exec sh -c 'ls -1 "{}"|egrep -i -q "^cover\.(jpg|png)$"' ';' -print
```

#### Explanation:

- You need to spawn a shell `sh` for each directory since piping isn't possible when using `find`
- `ls -1 "{}"` outputs just the filenames of the directory `find` is currently traversing
- `egrep` (instead of `grep`) uses extended regular expressions; `-i` makes the search case insensitive, `-q` makes it omit any output
- `"^cover\.(jpg|png)$"` is the search pattern. In this example, it matches e.g. `cOver.png`, `Cover.JPG` or `cover.png`. The `.` must be escaped otherwise it means that it matches *any* character. `^` marks the start of the line, `$` its end

**Other search pattern examples for egrep**:

Substitute the `egrep -i -q "^cover\.(jpg|png)$"` part with:

- `egrep -i -q "cover\.(jpg|png)$"` : Also matches `cd_cover.png`, `album_cover.JPG` ...
- `egrep -q "^cover\.(jpg|png)$"` : Matches `cover.png`, `cover.jpg`, but NOT `Cover.jpg` (case sensitivity is not turned off)
- `egrep -iq "^(cover|front)\.jpg$"` : matches e.g. `front.jpg`, `Cover.JPG` but *not* `Cover.PNG`

For more info on this, check out [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: Absolutely beautiful — with the problem that it's not flexible to pick between cases or different extensions (I tried a wildcard but no-go). I wonder if there's a better alternative to `test`.

Comment: Hmm you can nest the find with this `-exec bash -c '[[ -n $(find "{}" -iname "cover.*") ]]' \;` but that's pretty filthy in terms of optimisation. It does work though.

Comment: I found that you can pass `test` a load of `-o EXPRESSION` for OR queries... eg: `test -e "{}/cover.jpg" -o -e "{}/cover.png"` which is better than doing a full blown search but it's still case sensitive.

Comment: I should note that comparing the performance of this (two tests, per my last comment) against the other two solutions (comm'd find and comm'd globbing) this is by far the slowest (684ms vs 40ms and 50ms respectively)

Comment: The original in-answer solution takes over a second and breaks in circumstances that have `$` in the dir name (Ke$ha, for example).

Comment: Almost downvoted as not working, but then I saw the `- print` at the end. Works beautifully!

Comment: Case 2 is the only thing I could get to work for a situation where I was searching in a directory for subdirectories that did not contain pdf files, and the subdirectory names contained spaces and commas, and the pdf files had unpredictable names so I had to find them with `"*.pdf"`.

Comment: I had no idea you could use -exec as a predicate. That's an awesome trick for other uses, too.

Answer (score 13):

Simple, it transpires. The following gets a list of directories with the cover and compares that with a list of all the second-level directories. Lines that appear in both "files" are suppressed, leaving a list of directories that need covers.

```
comm -3 \
    <(find ~/Music/ -iname 'cover.*' -printf '%h\n' | sort -u) \
    <(find ~/Music/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d | sort) \
| sed 's/^.*Music\///'
```

Hooray.

Notes:

- `comm`'s arguments are as follows:

  - `-1` suppress lines unique to file1
  - `-2` suppress lines unique to file2
  - `-3` suppress lines that appear in both files
- `comm` only takes files, hence the kooky `<(...)` input method. This pipes the content via a real [temporary] file.
- `comm` needs sorted input or it doesn't work and `find` does by no means guarantee an order. It also needs to be unique. The first `find` operation could find multiple files for `cover.*` so there could be duplicate entries. `sort -u` quickly ruffles those down to one. The second find is always going to be unique.
- `dirname` is a handy tool for getting a file's dir without resorting to `sed` (et al).
- `find` and `comm` are both a bit messy with their output. The final `sed` is there to clean things up so you're left with `Artist/Album`. This may or may not be desirable for you.

Comment: your first `find` can possibly be simplified to `find ~/Music/ -iname 'cover.*' -printf '%h\n'`, avoiding the need for `dirname`. though `dirname` is handy elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks @Tom, that is a *lot* faster that forking out everywhere (29ms vs 734ms on my music dir - both "warm" finds)

Answer (score 9):

This is much nicer to solve with globbing than with find.

```
$ cd ... # to the directory one level above the album/artist structure

$ echo */*/*.cover   # lists all the covers

$ printf "%s\n" */*/*.cover # lists all the covers, one per line
```

Now suppose you have no stray files in this nice structure. The current directory contains only artist subdirectories, and those contain only album subdirectories. Then we can do something like this:

```
$ diff  <(for x in */*/cover.jpg; do echo "$(dirname "$x")" ; done) <(printf "%s\n" */*)
```

The `<(...)` syntax is Bash process substitution: it lets you use a command in place of a file argument. It lets you treat the output of a command as a file.  So we can run two programs, and take their diff, without saving their output in temporary files. The `diff` program thinks it is working with two files, but in fact it's reading from two pipes.

The command that produces the right hand input to `diff`, `printf "%s\n" */*`, just lists the album directories. The left hand command iterates through the `*.cover` paths and prints their directory names.

Test run:

```
$ find .   # let's see what we have here
.
./a
./a/b
./foo
./foo/bar
./foo/baz
./foo/baz/cover.jpg

$ diff  <(for x in */*/cover.jpg; do echo "$(dirname "$x")" ; done) <(printf "%s\n" */*)
0a1,2
> a/b
> foo/bar
```

Aha, the `a/b` and `foo/bar` directories have no `cover.jpg`.

There are some broken corner cases, like that by default `*` expands to itself if it matches nothing. This can be addressed with Bash's `set -o nullglob`.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. It's an interesting idea but: covers can be in png and jpb and , wouldn't `comm` be cleaner than `diff`?

Comment: `comm -3 <(printf "%s\n" */*/cover* | sed -r 's/\/[^\/]+$//' | sort -u) <(printf "%s\n" */*)` seems like a sensible compromise without any of `diff`'s fluff. It is, however, a little bit slower than my double-find.

Answer (score 3):

Let's make it simple and easy to understand.

```shell
for dir in /*/*; do
  if [ ! -f $dir/cover.jpg ] && [ ! -f $dir/cover.png ]; then
    echo $dir
  fi
done
```

Make it one line (note that we need an extra `;` in the one-line version):

```shell
for dir in /*/*; do if [ ! -f $dir/cover.jpg ] && [ ! -f $dir/cover.png ]; then echo $dir; fi done
```

Comment: Finally!  No inscrutable `find` incantations, no temporary files, just a simple answer to a simple question.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls --color=never */*.txt | sed 's|/.*||' | sort -u -n > withtxt.txt
ls --color=never -d * | sort -u -n > all.txt
diff all.txt withtxt.txt
```

Will show all directories that do not have txt files in them.