# Find directories that DON'T contain a file but YES another one

Tags: directory, find

I have quite a large music collection and would like to find the directories in which I still have compressed files (*.rar) unprocessed. Hence looking for a command that lists directories in which i do NOT have *.flac or *.mp3 but YES *.rar present. Working off found examples in this post:

- [Find directories that DON'T contain a file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196960/find-directories-that-dont-contain-a-file)

I tried:

```
comm -3 \
    <(find ~/Music/ -iname "*.rar" -not -iname "*.flac" -not -iname "*.mp3" -printf '%h\n' | sort -u) \
    <(find ~/Music/ -maxdepth 5 -mindepth 2 -type d | sort) \
| sed 's/^.*Music\///'
```

but don' work.

Comment: You could use `ls -R ~/Music | grep .rar` to find files with a filename containing '.rar' - this will just find and list the .rar files. This may work better than the `find` command.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381373/search-for-directories-containing-one-file-and-missing-another

Answer (score 1):

The following command will list all directories that don't contain `.flac` or `.mp3` files:

```
find ~/Music -type d '!' -exec sh -c 'ls -1 "{}"|egrep -iq "^*\.(flac|mp3)$" ' ';' -print
```

And the following command will list all directories that contain `.rar` files:

```
find ~/Music -type d -exec sh -c 'ls -1 "{}"|egrep -iq "^*\.rar$"' ';' -print
```

Now, joining these commands, the following command  will list all directories that don't contain `.flac` or `.mp3` files and that contain `.rar` files:

```
find ~/Music -type d -exec sh -c 'ls -1 "{}"|egrep -iq "^*\.rar$"' ';' \
    '!' -exec sh -c 'ls -1 "{}"|egrep -iq "^*\.(mp3|flac)$" ' ';' -print
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation. Neat script! Discovered some interesting hidden corners in my collection...

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```
find . -iname '*.rar' -exec bash -c 'cd "${1%/*}"; 
  shopt -s nullglob; files=(*.flac *.mp3); 
  ((${#files[@]} == 0)) && echo "$1"' _ {} \;
```

explanation: for every .rar, take its base dir, list *.flac and *.mp3, and if the list is empty print the filename.

Comment: THANK YOU TO ALL!! I appreciate your time and knowledge. All work like a charm. Respectfully m~

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a more elegant way of doing this, but naively I would want to

- Get a list of directories containing *.rar files (with `find` and `sort -u`)
- Get a list of directories containing *.mp3 and *.flac files (also with `find`)
- Subtract this second list from the first (using `grep -v`)

So:

```
find . -iname '*.rar' -printf '%h\n' | sort -u > lista.txt
find . -iregex '.*\(.mp3\|.flac\)' -printf '%h\n' | sort -u > listb.txt
grep -v -f listb.txt lista.txt
```

You can do it without having to resort to temporary files by using process substitution, as in the attempt in your question:

```
grep -v -f <(find . -iregex '.*\(.mp3\|.flac\)' -printf '%h\n' | sort -u) \
<(find . -iname '*.rar' -printf '%h\n' | sort -u)
```